# Why is the db connection to migrate silently failing?

Tags: database, 10

I'm using D10, drush 12, ddev.
In settings.local.php I have:

```
$databases['migrate']['default'] = array (
  'database'  => 'd7',
  'username'  => 'db',
  'password'  => 'db',
  'host'      => 'db',
  'port'      => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
);
```

In the code when I do:

```
$db = Database::getAllConnectionInfo();
```

the var_dump shows 'migrate' being part of the array:

```
array(2) {
  ["default"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["default"]=>
    array(11) {
      ["database"]=>
      string(2) "db"
      ["username"]=>
      string(2) "db"
      ["password"]=>
      string(2) "db"
      ["host"]=>
      string(2) "db"
      ["port"]=>
      int(3306)
      ["driver"]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["prefix"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["namespace"]=>
      string(34) "Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql"
      ["autoload"]=>
      string(45) "core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/"
      ["pdo"]=>
      array(6) {
        [3]=>
        int(2)
        [1000]=>
        bool(true)
        [1005]=>
        bool(true)
        [20]=>
        bool(true)
        [1013]=>
        bool(false)
        [17]=>
        bool(true)
      }
      ["init_commands"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["sql_mode"]=>
        string(33) "SET sql_mode = 'ANSI,TRADITIONAL'"
      }
    }
  }
  ["migrate"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["default"]=>
    array(9) {
      ["database"]=>
      string(2) "d7"
      ["username"]=>
      string(2) "db"
      ["password"]=>
      string(2) "db"
      ["host"]=>
      string(2) "db"
      ["port"]=>
      string(4) "3306"
      ["driver"]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["prefix"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["namespace"]=>
      string(34) "Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql"
      ["autoload"]=>
      string(45) "core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/"
    }
  }
}
```

but when I try to create a connection, with

```
return Database::getConnection('migrate');
```

I receive:

```
In ExceptionHandler.php line 46:
                                                                                                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.node_type' doesn't exist: SELECT `name`,`type`,`description` from node_type ORDER BY `name`; Array  
  (                                                                                                                                                                 
  )                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                    

In StatementWrapperIterator.php line 110:
                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.node_type' doesn't exist
```

and dumping the connection variable shows a connection to the default db but not to the migrate db.

Let me add context and more code. I began with a working module for D10 providing a drush 12 custom command. At that point, the command made no use of a database. I simply wanted to add an option to the command that makes use of a database. I mention this for two reasons: to point out that the structure of using a drush custom command had  already bene in place and working, and to point out that this is a drush command, in case it could be how drush interacts with the database(s) that makes a difference.

I had been bootstrapping drush to the configuration level. In adding the new feature I upped that to the database level:

```
  #[CLI\Bootstrap(level: DrupalBootLevels::DATABASE)]
```

I added the following *use* entries:

```
  use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
  use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
```

Once I have determined that the drush command has been entered with the option request to use the database, I call the method to establish the connection and do a simple query (I prefer to added new functionality in steps...easier to test).

```
if ($options['db']) {
  $db = $this->getD7DbConnection();
  if (!$db) {
    $this->logger()->error(dt("There is no migrate database configured in the site settings."));
    return NULL;
  }
  $file = Drupal::service('extension.path.resolver')->getPath('module', 'mymodule') . '/data/items.db.yml';
  return $this->scanDb($db, $file);
}
```

This method succeeds. It contains the db connection info showing two db's, default and migrate, shown above in the var_dump:

private function getD7DbConnection() {
$db = Database::getAllConnectionInfo();
if (isset($db['migrate'])) {
return Database::getConnection('migrate');
}

```
return FALSE;
```

}

This method then fails. I threw a simple query into it for now just to prove or disprove a connection:

private function scanDb(Connection $db, $file) {
$results = $db->query('SELECT * from node_type ORDER BY `name`;');

```
return $results;
```

}

And that's all there is. At this point I'm simply attempting to connect to the db, as a result of the request via drush option, and do a simple query.

Comment: This question needs to include more of the custom code, to explain what function is returning that database connection. It can’t be answered without that.

Comment: Quite right @cilefen. I've added all the applicable code as well as needed context, above.

Comment: Y'all are a bit too quick to vote down a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that getConnection parameters are (target, key), so
('default', 'migrate') rather than ('migrate', 'default').